# How do I open a docx for writing?

Tags: c#, ms-word

I need to open a word file for writing. This is the code I have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, `EventArgs` e)
{
    var wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();

    object useDefaultValue = Type.Missing;
    object readnly = false;
    object visibe = true;
    wordApp.Documents.Open("f:\\test2.docx");
}
```

But it opens my file in read-only. Why?

Comment: Uh. You never actually use the flags you declare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me

```
Word._Application oWord;
Word._Document oDoc;
object oMissing = Type.Missing;
oWord = new Word.Application();
oWord.Visible = true;

//Add Blank sheet to Word App
oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add(ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing); 

oWord.Selection.TypeText("Write your text here");
```